# facebook moving from HTTP to HTTPS is there a possibility to combine likes count?

Tags: facebook, http, https, facebook-like

I moved my site from HTTP to HTTPS now a few days later my facebook likes are waaay lower.  For example one article under HTTP was 25K likes now under HTTPS it is 3K likes . Is there a way to combine (add) the two numbers under HTTPS?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to combine (add) the two numbers under HTTPS?

No. Facebook treats them as two different Open Graph objects.

But you can get the likes of the old HTTP URLs back, by following the instructions outlined in [Social Plugins FAQ: How do I move a page to a different URL?](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/faqs#faq_1149655968420144)